# Embedded power bi report export to pdf

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to export embedded report as pdf format.I can download the report without pagination now I am trying to download thr first page of the report which is  returning Badrequest response from the ExportToFileInGroupAsync() API.

The report which I test one is not have any RLS roles.

```
 public async Task<FileModel> ExportPaginatedReport(string Token, Guid WorkspaceId, Guid ReportId, string ExportName, FileFormat ExportFileFormat, string userName, string OutputFormat = "pdf", List<ParameterValue> Parameters = null)
    {
            FileModel fileModel = new FileModel();

                var embededParams = await GetEmbedParams(WorkspaceId, ReportId, ReportAccessLevel.View, null, null);
                using (var pbiClient = await GetPowerBiClient())
                {
                    var report = await pbiClient.Reports.GetReportInGroupAsync(WorkspaceId, ReportId);

                    var exportRequest = new ExportReportRequest
                    {
                        Format = ExportFileFormat,
                        PaginatedReportConfiguration = new 
                        PaginatedReportExportConfiguration
                        {
                            ParameterValues = new List<ParameterValue>() { },
                            FormatSettings = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                            {"StartPage", "1" },
                            {"EndPage","1"}
                        },
                            Identities = new List<EffectiveIdentity>()
                            {
                                new EffectiveIdentity
                                {
                                   //IdentityBlob =  new IdentityBlob {
                                   //    Value = embededParams.EmbedToken.Token
                                   // },
                                   Username = _embeddedAnalyticsConfig.Username,
                                  Datasets = new List<string> { report.DatasetId },
                                  Roles = null

                                },
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    if (Parameters != null)
                    {
                        exportRequest.PaginatedReportConfiguration.ParameterValues = Parameters;
                    }

                    Export export = await pbiClient.Reports.ExportToFileInGroupAsync(WorkspaceId, ReportId, exportRequest);
                    
                    ///Rest of polling and export codes
                }
    }
```

Error: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest

Note - The same report I can download without the Pagination, at that time I used the PowerBIReportExportConfiguration object in ExportRequest

Comment: Can you comment out the Datasets line in code and run it. I guess badrequest hits because of report.DatasetId. Not sure we require the line to export the paginated report. https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-paginated-report

If not for Bad request, please review the information in the exception, it should hint us what is the reason behind the error

Answer (score -1):

```
public   void ExportPaginatedReport(Guid WorkspaceId, Guid ReportId, string ExportName, FileFormat ExportFileFormat, PowerBIClient pbiClient , string OutputFormat = "pdf", List<ParameterValue> Parameters = null)
    {
        try
        {
          
            //1
            List<ParameterValue> lstpv = new List<ParameterValue>();
            ParameterValue pv = new ParameterValue()
            {
                Name = "BillingMonthYear",
                Value = "202303"
            };

            lstpv.Add(pv); // Add a ParameterValue object to the list


            //2
            var exportRequest = new ExportReportRequest
            {
                Format = ExportFileFormat,
                PaginatedReportConfiguration = new PaginatedReportExportConfiguration
                {
                    ParameterValues = lstpv,
                    FormatSettings = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
                        {
                        
                                { "OutputFormat", OutputFormat }

                        }
                }
            };




           //3
            Export export = pbiClient.Reports.ExportToFileInGroup(WorkspaceId, ReportId, exportRequest);


            Console.WriteLine("Exporting " + ExportName + " (paginated report) to " + ((ExportFileFormat.Equals(FileFormat.IMAGE)) ? OutputFormat.ToUpper() : ExportFileFormat.ToString()));

            string exportId = export.Id;

            do
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                export = pbiClient.Reports.GetExportToFileStatusInGroup(WorkspaceId, ReportId, exportId);
                Console.WriteLine(" - Export status: " + export.PercentComplete.ToString() + "% complete");
            } while (export.Status != ExportState.Succeeded && export.Status != ExportState.Failed);

            if (export.Status == ExportState.Failed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Export failed!");
            }


            if (export.Status == ExportState.Succeeded)
            {
                ispaginated = true;
                string FileName = ExportName + export.ResourceFileExtension.ToLower();

                string FilePath = filepath + FileName;

                Console.WriteLine(" - Saving exported file to " + FilePath);
                var exportStream = pbiClient.Reports.GetFileOfExportToFileInGroup(WorkspaceId, ReportId, exportId);
                FileStream fileStream = File.Create(FilePath);
                exportStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                fileStream.Close();

             

            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        catch (Exception exx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exx.ToString() );
         
        }

      

    }
```